# Node mongoose always returning error on findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using passport.js to sign in users, and whenever my local authentication function gets to User.findOne(), it always returns with an error. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

my passport code with the findOne() call:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serialize user occurred');
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});




passport.use('local-signup',
    new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {

        // asynchronous
        // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
        process.nextTick(function() {
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) // An error occurred
                    console.log(err);
                    err.toString();
                    return done(err);
                if (user) { // This email is already in use
                    return done(null, false);
                } else { // Valid email to sign in wth
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.local.email = email;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
);
```

And my user model:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local : {
        email : String,
        password : String
    },
    facebook : {
        id : String,
        token : String,
        email : String,
        name : String
    }
});

// methods ==============
// Generate a hash for a password
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password){
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// Checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and my routes if you're interested:

```
app.get('/signupfail', function(req, res) {
    // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
    res.json({message: "failed to sign in, failure redirect"});
});

// process the signup form
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/signupfail', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    falureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));

app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var user = req.user // This is the user extracted from the session
    res.json({message: "hooray it worked for: "+user.local.email});
});
```

I'm honestly terrible with node, but I want to learn!

Comment: What is the error printed to the console?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't print anything to the console, because of it's threading (the outer function finishes before the log does), however, through the use of err.toString(), I can guess that the err === null since err.toString() throws an error saying that you can't call toString() on null. Maybe that's a poor assumption though. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passport.use('local-signup',
 ...
    function(req, email, password, done) {
```

The function expect three arguments `email, password,done`.
change the callback function to

```
function( email, password, done) {
```

Comment: I changed it, but it's still not working. Btw I know I'm not an expert, but I had 4 arguments, because I set 'passReqToCallback' as true, but I wasn't using it, so regardless, it was a good idea to get rid of it and make that change as well

Comment: So sorry, I have never used  `passReqToCallback` before.

Comment: No worries, by any chance do you know why my question is being downvoted? I'm not sure how my question was bad

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem.

Listen here kids, always wrap your jimmy, and always close your if statements

Comment: if (err) // An error occurred
                    console.log(err);
                    err.toString();
                    return done(err);// here? my god...I haven't seen it either.
maybe it is a good idea to develop with ide such as webstorm and frequently format our code.